Trying to find a way to work out current scoring sequence that needs to cross reference with number of games played by team
I have a list of scorers and how many times they score in each match.
Is there a way to find out the current scoring streak depending on how many games their team has played?
text
The entries in column H are the expected return. More columns will appear between columns F and G.
Row 3 - Player's team have played 2 games so he is on a 2 game streak
Row 9 - Player's team have played 3 games and he didn't score in game 3, so his streak is 0
Googling for similar questions, couldn't find any. I can work out the best total of consecutive games scores in, but not a current total.

let's take row 6 as an example. It says 2 games played but how do we know which 2 games were played? The sheet assumes 1 and 2 therefore a streak of 1. But if the games played were 2 and 3 the streak would be 0.

games are/will be played in order 1,2,3 up to 23 as a max.

Assuming "games played" prioritizes early games (i.e. "k games played" means "the first k games were played"), you could try something like this:
=LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(,FILTER(IF(COUNTIF(C3:E3,1,0),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(C3:E3))<=K3)),"1+$"))

Or with a single formula:
=MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(C3:E)),LAMBDA(i,LET(
   r,INDEX(C3:E,i),
   IF(COUNTA(r)=0,,
     LEN(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(,
       FILTER(IF(r,1,0),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(r))<=INDEX(K3:K,i))),"1+$"))))))) 


Sir, that is just fantastic. I have substituted into the correct google sheet and changed columns accordingly and haven't broken it.  Thank you so much!
